# Automapper mapping issues child object properties

Tags: c#, automapper

Following different questions/**answers** about this topic here Im having difficulties with AutoMapper which I start using it 2 days ago.

This is my Model (Front):

```
public class AlumnoModel
{
    #region Fields
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Legajo { get; set; }
    public int Dni { get; set; }
    public TurnoModel Turno { get; set; }
    public CarreraModel Carrera { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

this is my Domain (Created by EF doing code first using a local Database)

```
public partial class Alumnos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Legajo { get; set; }

    public int Dni { get; set; }

    public int Carrera { get; set; }

    public int Turno { get; set; }

    public virtual Carreras Carreras { get; set; }

    public virtual Turnos Turnos { get; set; }
}
```

This is how Im trying to map them:

```
public Alumnos FromModelToDomain_Alumnos(AlumnoModel alumno)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Alumnos, AlumnoModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Nombre, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Nombre))
        .ForMember(d => d.Apellido, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Apellido))
        .ForMember(d => d.Legajo, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Legajo))
        .ForMember(d => d.Dni, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Dni))
        .ForMember(d => d.Turno, s => s.MapFrom(src => new Carreras
            {
                Id = src.Turnos.Id,
                Descripcion = src.Turnos.Descripcion
            }))
        .ForMember(d => d.Carrera, s => s.MapFrom(src => new Turnos
            {
                Id = src.Carreras.Id,
                Descripcion = src.Carreras.Descripcion
            }))
        .ForMember(d => d.Carrera.Id, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Carrera))
        .ForMember(d => d.Turno.Id, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Turno));
    });

    return Mapper.Map<Alumnos>(alumno);
}
```

This is the message of the Exception:

```
Expression 'd => d.Carrera.Id' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.
Parameter name: lambdaExpression.
```

I will read more about `AfterMap` but I thought creating a new instace of the childs and filling their properties would be enough to then make the mapping.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I made some changes to the mapper method, it looks like this:

```
public Alumnos FromModelToDomain_Alumnos(AlumnoModel alumno)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<AlumnoModel, Alumnos>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Nombre, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Nombre))
        .ForMember(d => d.Apellido, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Apellido))
        .ForMember(d => d.Legajo, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Legajo))
        .ForMember(d => d.Dni, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Dni))
        .ForMember(d => d.Turnos, s => s.MapFrom(src => new Carreras
        {
            Id = src.Turno.Id,
        }))
        .ForMember(d => d.Carreras, s => s.MapFrom(src => new Turnos
        {
            Id = src.Carrera.Id,
        }))
        .ForMember(d => d.Carrera, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Carrera.Id))
        .ForMember(d => d.Turno, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Turno.Id));
    });

    return Mapper.Map<Alumnos>(alumno);
}
```

If I take the `new` out of there It works but of course those properties will be emtpy.

Message Of Exception:

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
AlumnoModel -> Alumnos
Prog_II.Models.AlumnoModel -> Repository.Domain.Alumnos

Type Map configuration:
AlumnoModel -> Alumnos
Prog_II.Models.AlumnoModel -> Repository.Domain.Alumnos

Property:
Turnos
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found a solution, maybe it is a bit bulky but It did the job:

```
public AlumnoModel FromDomainToModel_Alumnos(Alumnos alumno)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Turnos, TurnoModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Id, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        .ForMember(d => d.Descripcion, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Descripcion));

        cfg.CreateMap<Carreras, CarreraModel>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Id, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        .ForMember(d => d.Descripcion, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Descripcion));

        cfg.CreateMap<AlumnoModel, Alumnos>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Nombre, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Nombre))
        .ForMember(d => d.Apellido, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Apellido))
        .ForMember(d => d.Legajo, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Legajo))
        .ForMember(d => d.Dni, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Dni))
        .ForMember(d => d.Carrera, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Carrera.Id))
        .ForMember(d => d.Turno, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Turno.Id))

        .ForMember(d => d.Turnos, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Turno))
        .ForMember(d => d.Carreras, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Carrera));
    });

    return Mapper.Map<AlumnoModel>(alumno);
}
```

I dont understand why initializing the other Domains did not work.
Here we are telling Automapper that everytime you want to map an `Alumnos` and you find an `Turnos` and `Carreras` inside of it, use the `.CreateMap` above to resolve it.

You have to be inside Initialize (inside the instance of what is going to be mapped what with what).